# Is there any short method to see all changes made in a particular file on comparing two different releases of a software on github?

Tags: git, github

While working on a project I needed to see all changes made in a particular file in 2 different releases of a software. In my case I was working on JSettlers and while comparing version 2.6.00 with 2.5.00 hosted at https://github.com/jdmonin/JSettlers2/compare/release-2.5.00...release-2.6.00   I wanted to see all changes made in a file named SOCServer.java . First 18 changes were made in that file on 10 January, then 64 changes on 16 January and so on multiple changes made on same file multiple times.
So I want to see all the changes made in any file but do not want to see each commit and then add up all those changes to see how many total changes were made to that file. Is there any short way to do so?

I tried comparing different versions on github to see all the changes made in a particular file but could not find any method to do so.

Comment: If you switch to the "Files changed" tab and scroll to that file, [here](https://github.com/jdmonin/JSettlers2/compare/release-2.5.00...release-2.6.00#diff-e446248b88f5e80aabd4d02bd59e772cd22c98810543252ef56fcc67934dec83), isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. What a rookie mistake. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I know your question is about GitHub, but just as a tip, in case it's useful: I use Visual Studio Code, with the extension Git Graph and works like a charm. You can do a lot there very intuitively and directly in your local repo. That way you don't change your remote repo unless you push or do a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

[`git diff [<options>] <commit>..<commit> [--] [<path>…​]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) shows the difference in a file between two arbitrary points in the development history of a file or files.